# predefined input and passing to ng-model in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem Question -

I have a input box which displays the value, but now I want to update the value on click.

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in money">
     <td><input type="text" ng-model="value.cent">
          <button ng-controller="updateCentController"
            ng-click="updateCent(product.id,value.cent)">Update</button>
     </td>
</tr>
```

But how would I pass updated ng-model as a parameter to the ng-click? Am I doing something wrong?

Update -

Problem Has been fixed. It was in my controller

Comment: You already doing it, in second argument

Comment: Nope, it keeps on giving undefined. Its not passing to the controller

Comment: Can you show the updateCent function?

Comment: Thanks @DaveWalker I found the Problem :)

Comment: Um - cool! :D Is it some lesson that can be shared if so add an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Everything should be in the same scope in the controller:

```
<div ng-controller="updateCentController">
<tr ng-repeat="value in money">
     <td><input type="text" ng-model="value.cent">
          <button
            ng-click="updateCent(product.id,value.cent)">Update</button>
     </td>
</tr>
</div>
```